# Whistle-stop tour

Tags: meaning, etymology

I came across this phrase 'Whistle-stop tour' while reading an article. Please throw a light on it's origin and meaning.

Comment: Looking at these might help: [Freedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+whistle-stop+tour); [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistle_stop_train_tour); [World Wide words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-whi5.htm), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**whistle-stop tour**

The true definition of the term derives from the practice of a small, only occasionally used railway station of signaling a train by steam whistle so the engineer will know to stop to pick up a passenger. Therefore, the first usage of the term in the political context, by Robert Taft, was derisive. He accused then President Harry S. Truman of "blackguarding Congress at whistle stops across the country".

Source : Wiki

Use of the term has spread **to cover any travel done very quickly** and with only brief pauses. It is common to hear this expression in the United States, where the term originated, as well as the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a tour where someone gets in and gets out of a city/location quickly and moves to the next city for the same thing a few times a day.

When train was the only viable quick form of travel politicians did whistle stop tours where basically they could talk for a few minutes in each town while the train was stopped and unloading/loading.  They might have 20 minutes to make a speech and then be on to the next town an hour later.